# Difference between DECLARE_DYNAMIC and DECLARE_DYNCREATE?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Could you please let me know what is difference between `DECLARE_DYNAMIC` and `DECLARE_DYNCREATE`?

Where exactly we can use them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should i use DECLARE\_DYNAMIC instead of DECLARE\_DYNCREATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879680/why-should-i-use-declare-dynamic-instead-of-declare-dyncreate)

Comment: @IInspectable, this question was asked in year 2009, and you are marking the question which is asked in year 2015. I would recommend you to do in reverse order. mark your latest question as duplicate of this very old question.

Comment: The term duplicate has no notion of time. The fact that a question that was asked later turned this question into a duplicate doesn't make this question any less of a duplicate. I marked this as a duplicate of another question, because that other question is more to the point, and offers a more detailed explanation. Marking a question as a duplicate helps future visitors to see, that there is another Q&A that's largely identical, but may provide more information. It is not meant as a tool to communicate the order of historic events.

Comment: See [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/205381) Specifically: *"The general rule is to **keep the question with the best collection of answers**, and close the other one as a duplicate."*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first declares that a class has runtime type info and the second that instances can be created dynamically at runtime. This is described in detail in the MSDN documentation - see links like [Run-Time Object Model Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/run-time-object-model-services) for more info.

Comment: Also note that if you use `DECLARE_DYNCREATE` in the header file, you must be certain to match this with `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` in the source file.  (Ditto for the others.)