# Can I convert 'DECLARE_DYNCREATE' to 'DECLARE_DYNAMIC'?

Tags: mfc

I want to implement popup dialog by inheriting CMFCDesktopAlertDialog class. However, this class can only be used by declaring the 'DECLARE_DYNCREATE' macro.

Is there a way to declare the 'DECLARE_DYNAMIC' macro instead of 'DECLARE_DYNCREATE' and create myself within code ?

Comment: Quick answer: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886774/1889329).

Comment: Have DECLARE_DYNCREATE (and IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE) for your derived class doesn't stop you from 'creating yourself within code'. Just do stuff as you would for any other (CDialogEx-derived) class. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcdesktopalertdialog-class?view=vs-2019