# Microsft Visual Studio C++ 2019 compile error with IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I am developing a program that needs to run multitask so that I can have a timer running.

Here is the include file (`MyRunTimers.h`):

```
#pragma once
#include <afxwin.h>

class MyRunTimers :
    public CObject
{
    int     m_nNum;
    bool m_bDone = FALSE;
    CObject* m_pOwner = NULL;
    bool m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;

    void MyTimerThread();

public:
     DECLARE_DYNAMIC(MyRunTimers)

protected:
    MyRunTimers::MyRunTimers();

    MyRunTimers::~MyRunTimers();

};
```

Here is the cpp file (`MyRunTimers.cpp`):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MyRunTimers.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(MyRunTimers, CObject)

MyRunTimers::MyRunTimers()
{
    m_bDone = FALSE;
    m_pOwner = NULL;
    m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
}

MyRunTimers::~MyRunTimers()
{
}
```

When I try and compile the `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` is highlighted in red, and I get:

> ```
> `E0135 - class "MyRunTimers" has no member "CreateObject"
> ```

Comment: E0135 is not a compiler or linker error. Do you get any compiler or linker errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: You should also change `protected: MyRunTimers::MyRunTimers(); MyRunTimers::~MyRunTimers();` which is strictly speaking incorrect to `protected: MyRunTimers(); ~MyRunTimers();` There no need to use `MyRunTimers::` inside the class definition only outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `DECLARE_DYNAMIC(MyClass)` in the class declaration (header file), then you need `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(MyClass, BaseClass)` in the definition file.

Alternatively, if you actually *need* `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE()`, then you should have `DECLARE_DYNCREATE()` in the class definition.

For a discussion about the differences, see here: [Why should i use DECLARE_DYNAMIC instead of DECLARE_DYNCREATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879680/10871073).